# How to run CRONJob every 7 minutes after every 10 mins?

Tags: php, cron

I would like to create a cronjob to run every 7 minutes after every 10 minutes. For exmaple:

```
10:07
10:17
10:27
10:37
10:47
10:57
11:07
```

How is it possible? I've tried using `*/7 * * * *` but it's running the script every 7 minutes.

Comment: How not run it every 10 mins and start it at 10:07 ?

Comment: Ah so is it just: `7-59/10 * * * *`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer quickly by checking out more options.

Basically I had to run the script every 10 minutes starting at`:07`.

The correct answer is: `7-59/10 * * * *`

Thanks **@atayenel** for the hint.